# MVC4 Multiple Routes/ Multiple Domains and Sub Domains - General Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-routing, subdomain, maproute

Working on a MVC4 project where one of the domain has sub-domains and there are other 2 domains which should point to the same Global.asax.

All subdomains working fine but getting general exception when trying to open main domains

ex: www.pqr.com, www.mno.com (this has sub-domains)
ex: abc.mno.com, def.mno.com etc - these routes works ok

when i used Route Tester, all mappings seems ok

even Route Tester shows general exception. when we try to open www.pnr.com view opens with these special characters ��`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@������

If we add domain name (www.pnr.com) to routes, request is not matching with url/route
sample route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "www.pnr.com",
            url: "{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "pnr", action = "home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Controller.pnr" }
                );
```

What are we doing wrong? How do we fix this?

Comment: Could you include the output/stack trace from the exception? Also could you include a sample of your controller, the action you are testing and the associated view?

Comment: Issue Resolved Partially. Was problem due to Sub Domain Filters. now www.mno.com and abc.mno.com/ def.mno.com sites work

Comment: Need to figure out how www.pqr.com will work now....